# Do not count duplicate values in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Good morning,

I am having some problems with my current query, namely that duplicate values are being counted. This is, because in a pair table of two tables, values can appear twice.

The current query is as follows:

```
SELECT 

 BUY.SHIPMENT_XID BUYSHIPMENT,

 SELL.SHIPMENT_XID SELLSHIPMENT

FROM 

 SHIPMENT SELL, 

 V30_SHIPMENT_ORDER_RELEASE V30, 

 V30_SHIPMENT_ORDER_RELEASE V300, 

 SHIPMENT BUY

WHERE 

 SELL.PERSPECTIVE = 'S 

 AND SELL.SHIPMENT_GID = V30.SHIPMENT_GID 

 AND V30.ORDER_RELEASE_GID = V300.ORDER_RELEASE_GID 

 AND V300.PERSPECTIVE = 'B 

 AND V300.SHIPMENT_GID = BUY.SHIPMENT_GID
```

In the table shipment there is only the shipment number as shipment_gid and perspective indicating whether it is a buy shipment or a sellshipment via B or S

Example data:

| SHIPMENT_GID | PERSPECTIVE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | S |
| 3 | B |
| 4 | S |

To link a buy shipment to a sellshipment, oracle has the table: V30_SHIPMENT_ORDER_RELEASE. Here 3 fields are available: PERSPECTIVE, SHIPMENT_GID and ORDER_RELEASE_GID. By means of an ORDER_RELEASE_GID (or several) buy shipments are linked to a sellshipment.

Example data:

| SHIPMENT_GID | PERSPECTIVE | ORDER_RELEASE_GID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | B | RELEASE1 |
| 2 | S | RELEASE1 |
| 3 | B | RELEASE2 |
| 3 | B | RELEASE3 |
| 4 | S | RELEASE2 |
| 4 | S | RELEASE3 |

the result the above query should give is:

| BUYSHIPMENT | SELLSHIPMENT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |

the current query returns the following result

| BUYSHIPMENT | SELLSHIPMENT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 |

Comment: Do not use the old version of joining tables by using where. Use the modern `join`syntax

Comment: You can use ` group by` to prevent dupplicates

Comment: Why GROUP BY, @Jens, and not DISTINCT? I'd use GROUP BY if there were aggregates in the query (and there are none). DISTINCT seems to be a more *natural* choice. But yes, result would be the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
select DISTINCT b.SHIPMENT_GID as BUYSHIPMENT, s.SHIPMENT_GID as SELLSHIPMENT
from V30_SHIPMENT_ORDER_RELEASE b
join V30_SHIPMENT_ORDER_RELEASE s on s.PERSPECTIVE = 'S' and b.PERSPECTIVE= 'B' and s.ORDER_RELEASE_GID = b.ORDER_RELEASE_GID
```

(Assuming you have no orphan rows in the V30_SHIPMENT_ORDER_RELEASE table).

If you need other columns of SHIPMENT you can put it in a subquery and JOIN after the distinct pairs have been calculate.

Comment: Solution above is not working :(

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ed1dd/1